# Replace image file name by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

*I have find related answer but not same like this topic, so i asked this question.*

My question is, i'm trying to replace image file name `default.jpg` to `hqdefault.jpg` from all images below, I'm unable to change image links manually, so i have to change it by jquery.

**Images**

```
<div id="selector">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/qDc_5zpBj7s/default.jpg">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ss7EJ-PW2Uk/default.jpg">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ktd4_rCHTNI/default.jpg">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GTXMEPDpps/default.jpg">
</div>
```

**JS**  i'v tried

```
$('#selector img').attr('src',function(i,e){
    return e.replace("default.jpg","hqdefault.jpg");
});
```

Problem is it change(remove) whole links to `hqdefault.jpg`, but i **want to change only** `default.jpg` to `hqdefault.jpg` from all/any image src.

How to replace all image file name simply?

**Example**

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/qDc_5zpBj7s/default.jpg">
to
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/qDc_5zpBj7s/hqdefault.jpg">
```

Don't use full image link on js, because video generate image links/id dynamically, just replace `default.jpg` to `hqdefault.jpg` by jquery.

Comment: You missed id attribute. `<div="selector">` should be `<div id="selector">`

Comment: @Azim  ok, but, i'm using LaxyLoad XT plugin so result become like this: `hqhqhqdefault.jpg` . any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$('#selector img').attr('src',function(i,e){
    return $(this).attr('src').replace("default.jpg","hqdefault.jpg");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can also try this:

$('#selector img').on({
        'click': function(){
          var src1 = $(this).attr("src"); 
          var path = src1.substring(0,src1.lastIndexOf('/'));
          var new_source=path+'/'+'hqdefault.jpg';
            $(this).attr('src',new_source);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks, but, i'm unable to add any links on JS, want solution for only replace `default.jpg` without give full link on JS.

Comment: Hello ,I have made changes in my answer...try it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `each` function to iterate through all `img`. Following code snippet may help you.

```
$('#selector img').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace("default.jpg","hqdefault.jpg");
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

**Update:**
    If you are using LazyLoad XT plugin then do the same in it's `onload` event like following.

```
$.lazyLoadXT.onload=function(){
      var src = $(this).attr('src').replace("default.jpg","hqdefault.jpg");
      $(this).attr('src', src);
 }
```

Comment: hi i'm using LaxyLoad XT plugin so result become like this: `hqhqhqdefault.jpg` . any way to fix this?