# Trying to replace image file name with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab a image name and replace it. From `default.jpg` to `maxresdefault.jpg`. However, the script I'm using throws an error, when it seems to me it should be working.

HTML:

```
<a href="https://xxxxxxxxx.html" rel="nofollow" target="_self" title="Sample post with one video, part three">
  <div class="related-posts-thumb" itemprop="thumbnailURL" style="background: url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/iBy8UdG3VOo/default.jpg)"></div>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<!-- LET'S IMPROVE IMAGE QUALITY OF YOUTUBE THUMBNAILS IN THE RELATED POSTS -->
$('#main-content #Blog1 article .related-posts .related-content article .related-posts-thumb').each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("default.jpg", "maxresdefault.jpg"));
});
```

This returns the error: `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Just to compare, the script below the one that doesn't work, is a similar script that I use and it works just fine:

```
<!-- LET'S IMPROVE IMAGE QUALITY OF AVATARS IN THE COMMENTS -->
$('#main-content #Blog1 article #comments .comment .avatar-image-container img').each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("s35", "s72"));
});
```

Why is the script not working? Two similar scripts, one works, and one doesn't. I even tried the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971402/replace-image-file-name-by-jquery) at stackoverflow, but it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML shown, the `div` uses its `style` attribute for the image.

The second script works because it's replacing the `src` element of an `img` tag.

Since the `div` you're trying to modify doesn't have a `src` attribute, it's `undefined` and therefore doesn't respond to the method you're attempting to call.

Try this:

```
$('#main-content #Blog1 article .related-posts .related-content article .related-posts-thumb').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('style', $(this).attr('style').replace('default.jpg', 'maxresdefault.jpg'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change the src attribute, but there is no tag with a src attribute.  I added an img tag below as an example.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://xxxxxxxxx.html" rel="nofollow" 
   target="_self" 
   title="Sample post with one video, part three">
  <div class="related-posts-thumb"     
  itemprop="thumbnailURL" 
  style="background: url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/iBy8UdG3VOo/default.jpg); width:150px; height:100px;">
    content
  </div>
  Image tag with src attribute: 
  <br>
  <img id="myImg" src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/iBy8UdG3VOo/default.jpg' />
</a>
</body>
```

If you want to change the style tag background, edit that attribute instead.  this should work for the style:

```
$('.related-posts-thumb').each(function() {
  console.log('div style'+ $(this).attr("style") )
  myBgStyle=$(this).attr("style").replace("default.jpg", "maxresdefault.jpg");
  console.log('new bg style: '+myBgStyle)
  $(this).attr('style',myBgStyle);
});



  mySrc=$('#myImg').attr("src").replace("default.jpg", "maxresdefault.jpg");
  console.log('new image source: '+mySrc);
  $('#myImg').attr("src", mySrc);
```

See here:

https://jsbin.com/naqucipaza/edit?html,js,output

Comment: When I try to compress your script, it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The second line should be simpler:

```
$(this).attr("src", "maxresdefault.jpg"));
```

And in case you only want to apply this to images which have the `src` attribut "source.jpg", you should define that in the selector, so it should be

```
$('#main-content #Blog1 article .related-posts .related-content article .related-posts-thumb[src="source.jpg"]').each(function() {
   $(this).attr("src", "maxresdefault.jpg"));
});
```